# Transition position change when element removed from DOM

Tags: javascript

I have a vertical list of images that the user can delete by clicking on them. Once the element is removed from DOM, the next element in line snaps upward to its position. How can I do a smooth CSS transition for this position change?

http://jsbin.com/dewiqilope/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Are you using something like jQuery, or plain javascript?

Comment: I just use javascript to remove the element, but jquery is fine

Comment: Can you create a snippet?

Comment: With jQuery you can use $().fadeOut() or $().slideUp()

Comment: I added a snippet. How do I hook into all the other elements and tell them to slide up when I delete the clicked one?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what that function does. If you add slideUp as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery animations.

```
$('#element-selector').on('click', function () {
    $(this).slideUp(); // also you can use .fadeOut()
});
```